# TipKit configuration causing a crash

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, tipkit

I've gotten reports from a few users who are experiencing crashes related to this TipKit set up code in my App's Init method.  Xcode specifically points at this line `try Tips.configure([` as to the cause of the crash.  I can't figure out what could be happening here or how to fix?

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {

 init() {

     if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
                do {
                    try Tips.configure([
                        .displayFrequency(.immediate),
                        .datastoreLocation(.applicationDefault),
                    ])
                } catch {
                    print("Error configuring Tips: \(error)")
                }
            }
}


Crash Report: 

    Thread 0#0  (null) in __pthread_kill ()
    #1  (null) in pthread_kill ()
    #2  (null) in abort ()
    #3  (null) in swift::fatalErrorv(unsigned int, char const*, char*) ()
    #4  (null) in swift::fatalError(unsigned int, char const*, ...) ()
    #5  (null) in swift::ResolveAsSymbolicReference::operator()(swift::Demangle::__runtime::SymbolicReferenceKind, swift::Demangle::__runtime::Directness, int, void const*) ()
    #6  (null) in swift::Demangle::__runtime::Demangler::demangleSymbolicReference(unsigned char) ()
    #7  (null) in swift::Demangle::__runtime::Demangler::demangleType(__swift::__runtime::llvm::StringRef, std::__1::function<swift::Demangle::__runtime::Node* (swift::Demangle::__runtime::SymbolicReferenceKind, swi... ()
    #8  (null) in swift_getTypeByMangledNameImpl(swift::MetadataRequest, __swift::__runtime::llvm::StringRef, void const* const*, std::__1::function<void const* (unsigned int, unsigned int)>, std::__1::function<swif... ()
    #9  (null) in swift_getTypeByMangledName ()
    #10 (null) in swift_getTypeByMangledNameInContextImpl(char const*, unsigned long, swift::TargetContextDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const*, void const* const*) ()
    #11 (null) in __swift_instantiateConcreteTypeFromMangledName ()
    #12 (null) in specialized _allocateUninitializedArray<A>(_:) ()
    #13 0x0000000102785fd8 in newFitnessAppApp.init() at /Users/garysabo/AthlyticApp/tono/newFitnessApp/newFitnessAppApp.swift:47
    #14 (null) in static App.main() ()
    #15 (null) in static newFitnessAppApp.$main() ()
    #16 (null) in main ()
    #17 (null) in start ()
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"my App's Init method"*?

Comment: @DonMag ive edited my question to reflect it.

Comment: Can you reproduce this? Or, are you saying that *some* users are experiencing it *some* of the time?

Comment: @DonMag no I can't reproduce and definitely something that is not happening to most users, only a few reports and a large install base.  Has to be some variable, a friend suggested maybe they are out of storage space on the iPhone?

Comment: *"... maybe they are out of storage space ..."* - I suppose possible, but seems unlikely. Some quick searching -- is it possible these users have installed beta iOS versions?

Comment: @DonMag I think you're right.  Xcode says they are on iOS 17.0 (21A5248v) and (21A5291j) which are all previous beta's of iOS 17 and may be before TipKit was introduced.  